# kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh

if i do `systemctl status sshd`, the error shows below, could anyone show me how to fix it?

```
Jun 06 20:20:07 pj-server sshd[92565]: Failed password for root from 127.0.0.1 port 47644 ssh2
Jun 06 20:20:07 pj-server sshd[92565]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1 port 47644:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 06 20:20:07 pj-server sshd[92565]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 127.0.0.1 port 47644 [preauth]
Jun 06 20:20:08 pj-server sshd[92567]: Failed password for root from 127.0.0.1 port 47646 ssh2
Jun 06 20:20:08 pj-server sshd[92567]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1 port 47646:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 06 20:20:08 pj-server sshd[92567]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 127.0.0.1 port 47646 [preauth]
Jun 06 20:20:09 pj-server sshd[92585]: Failed password for root from 127.0.0.1 port 47648 ssh2
Jun 06 20:20:09 pj-server sshd[92585]: Received disconnect from 127.0.0.1 port 47648:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jun 06 20:20:09 pj-server sshd[92585]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 127.0.0.1 port 47648 [preauth]
Jun 06 20:20:14 pj-server sshd[92592]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Comment: You may checkout https://serverfault.com/questions/1015547/what-causes-ssh-error-kex-exchange-identification-connection-closed-by-remote